# Why does my background-color not fill all of my page?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="light">
<head>
.....
</head>
<body>
...
...
...
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
html.light body
{ background-color:#15293E ; }
```

I have text on my page that is long enought that a scroll bar appears. However when I scroll to the bottom
I notice the background color does not go all the way to the bottom of the page.

Is there something wrong with what I am doing. It's seems like simple HTML but I cannot get the background
color to fill the page.

Comment: try this background-color:#15293E !important;

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsbin.com/ocecuz/1/ — You have probably left a bit of your CSS that creates the problem out. Try providing a reduced test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DevangRathod — The background colour is clearly not being overridden, it wouldn't appear at all if it was.

Comment: I tried in Firefox and Chrome. With firebug and developer tools when I put my cursor over the words <body and <html then it highlights that area of the screen that has the background color. It's like the body does not extend to below the text on the screen.

Comment: also tell us which browser you are using

Comment: @Marilou — That's normal when the background isn't extending (it's very hard to make it look that way without the element coming short). You haven't shared the code that makes that happen though.

Comment: What other styles do you have on your html and body tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**:

- You have a fixed height like `height:100%` or `max-height` in your body/html styles

**Option 2**:

- Your content is floating or with `position:absolute` and thus the body is not extending as far as the content seems to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a hundred percent height for the roots:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

Comment: That is more likely to *create* this problem then fix it.

Comment: @Quentin Not *more likely*, but possible to fix or create, depending on peripheral styles etc.